# Batch If/Else not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I added this file to the Windows folder, so if I open `cmd` and type `EN`, I open my Minecraft Server console, but when I close the server, I want the cmd asking me if restart the server, but if I type something the cmd closes, someone can help me.

```cmd
@echo off
cd C:\Users\playl\Desktop\_\Server\EmeraldNetwork
start .
@echo on
start.bat
:1
set /p id="restart (Y/N): "
IF %id%==Y (
   start.bat
) 
ELSE IF %id%==N (
   exit
) 
ELSE (
   goto :1
)
```

EDIT: I got another problem, when I stop the server it says `press a key etc` and the cmd closes.

Comment: `)` and `ELSE` need to be on the same line

Comment: Thank you It works!
EDIT: I got another problem, when I stop the server it says 'press a key etc' and the cmd closes how to fix that^

Comment: If you run another  batch without using call it doesn't return to the originating batch. And for clarity change `start .` to `start.bat .`

Comment: with 'start .' I open the dir and with 'start.bat' I open the console, thanks for help! :)